# Try...except not catching NoSuchElementException in python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code below:

```
def test_counter(self):
    try:
        if self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.counter).text == 'texttexttext':
            return True
    except NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException:
        self.fix_error()
    return False
```

And I cannot figure out why the `NoSuchElementException` or the `StaleElementReferenceException` are not being caught.

Answer (score 7):

Change this line:

```
except NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException:
```

into:

```
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
```

This is the reason:

```
>>> NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException
StaleElementReferenceException
```

The `and` checks if `NoSuchElementException` is true first. Since this is case, it checks if `StaleElementReferenceException` is true. Because it also true, it returns this class.

Use [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) and it will warn you about this:

```
Exception to catch is the result of a binary "and" operation (binary-op-exception)
```

Answer (score 6):

[`A and B` become `B` if both `A` and `B` is truth values.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#and) So `NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException` become `StaleElementReferenceException`; The code is catching that exception only.

```
>>> NoSuchElementException and StaleElementReferenceException
<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException'>
```

You need to use `except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):` to catch both exceptions.

Comment: Hmm...`from foobar import *` isn't recommended.

Comment: @KevinGuan: For a well namedspaced package, assuming it really only includes the `selenium` specific exceptions, it's not so bad. It's annoying to need to qualify all the exceptions you might have to handle, or import them all explicitly by name.

Comment: Side-note: If you need to catch the exception and store it, you'd use `except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException) as somename:` (where `somename` is usually just `e`, but I wanted to make it clear the name is whatever you choose).

Comment: @KevinGuan, I did it for brevity.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Ah, yep. But however I'd prefer always use `from foo import bar` if you don't need all things in `foo`. That would be clear than `*`.

Comment: @KevinGuan, I removed the import line because it's not a point of the answer. Thank you for your feedback.